# Implicit conversion in c++ for between unsigned types of bit length ie uint8_t,uint16_t

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, static-cast, explicit-conversion

I would like to know how to implicit casting works in case of expressions between unsigned int of various bits ie uint8_t,uint16_t etc  and ways to avoid it explicitly. For this reason i sumarrized the following cases:

- How implicit casting in case of uint8_t addition,substraction,multiplication,division would work?

```
    uint8_t A;
    uint8_t B;
    uint16_t C;
    
    C= A+B; (uint8_t + uint8_t )
    C= A-B; (uint8_t + uint8_t )
    C= A*B; (uint8_t + uint8_t )
    C= A/B; (uint8_t + uint8_t )
```

Explicit declaration would be C= static_cast<uint16_t>A+B; or C= static_cast<uint16_t>(A+B);.Is this correct? Is there any difference between C= static_cast<uint16_t>A+B; or C= static_cast<uint16_t>(A+B)?

- How implicit casting in case of expressions of unsigned int(with U literal)and uint8_t  would work?
  Is there also a difference between the order that it matters ie 1U*B;(unsined int * uint8_t ) or B*1U;(uint8_t * uint8_t )

```
    C= A+1U;(uint8_t + uint8_t )
    C= A-1U;(uint8_t - uint8_t )
    C= 1U*B;(uint8_t * uint8_t )
    C= 1U/B;(uint8_t / uint8_t )
```

Explicit casting would be C= static_cast<uint16_t>A+1U; or C= static_cast<uint16_t>(A+1U);
C= static_cast<uint16_t>1U*B; or C= static_cast<uint16_t>(1U*B);.Is that correct
Is there any difference between those lines?

- How the implicit casting in case of expressions would work.Is the normal order take into account?
  What would it be the final type of the expression?

```
    C= 1U/(A-1U);  (unsigned int / (uint8_t -(unsigned int))
    C= (C-(A/B))/B; (uint8_t -(uint8_t /(unsigned int))/(uint8_t)
```

How should static_cast look in this case? Only the first variable (1U or C) would define for the rest
C= static_cast<uint8_t >(1U)/(A-1U);

- How the implicit casting in case of standard functions would work

```
    sizeof(A) returns size_t 
    C=abs(-1*A) returns int in case of int parmaters
```

Explicit casting would be C= static_cast<uint16_t>sizeof(A) and C= static_cast<uint16_t>abs(-1*A). Is that correct?
What about C= static_cast<uint16_t>abs(-1)*A)?

- How the implicit casting in case of function parameters would work.

```
    uint16_t sum(uint16_t C1,uint16_t C2);
    C=sum(A,B-1U/2U);           
    C=sum(A,1U/2U-B);
```

Explicit casting would  be  C= sum(static_cast<uint16_t>(A),static_cast<uint16_t>(B-1U/2U)). Is that correct?

I saw in Opencv a similar to static_cast function called saturate_cast. Would it be a beter solution in any of the above cases?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `The way to avoid` to avoid what? `The correct approach` Please define "correct".

Comment: @Cortex: Mainly i need to know how implicit casting order in an expression is perfomed. For example
    C= 1U/(A-1U);  (unsigned int / (uint8_t -(unsigned int))
    C= (C-(A/B))/B; (uint8_t -(uint8_t /(unsigned int))/(uint8_t)
what implicit type would it be returned for the above expressions on the right

Comment: @KamilCuk: I changed the description to be more understandable. Please see my comment above as bried summary of this question.

Comment: I think a good book and research would help you more then stackoverflow.

Comment: For example:
uint8_t A;
uint8_t B;
uint16_t C;
C= 1U/(A-1U); 

The left expressions type will end up to uint8_t  since this is the bigger type in(unsigned int / (uint8_t -(unsigned int)) and this uint8_t  will be implicitly casted to uint16_t. In other words, the final type of an expressions would end up be the biggest type on the expression if there are uint8_t and uint32_t it will be uint32_t . Is my assumption correct?

Comment: No, your assumption is wrong.

Comment: Ok, so what would be the final type of the expression would be?

Comment: Try not to guess programming. Instead research the actual rules. It's not magic, every corner case is exactly, explicitly and as clearly as possible described in the standard

Comment: There is no such thing as an implicit cast. The term you're looking for is **implicit conversion**. A cast is something you write in your source code (hence, always explicit) to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

> How implicit casting in case of uint8_t addition,substraction,multiplication,division would work?

`uint8_t` has *conversion rank* lesser then type `int` and type `int` can always hols the entire value range of `uint8_t`, `UINT8_MAX` is 255 and `int` has *at least* 16 bits. `uint8_t` will be promoted to `int` by *integral promotion* prior to operator. [cppreference integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) [fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) [cstdint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)

> Explicit declaration would be C= static_cast<uint16_t>A+B; or C= static_cast<uint16_t>(A+B);. Is this correct?

No. These are not examples of declarations, type specifier is missing. They are using `operator=` to assign a value to object `C`. An "explicit declaration" would be a declaration that uses the `auto` keyword. [cppreference declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations)

> Is there any difference between C= static_cast<uint16_t>A+B; or C= static_cast<uint16_t>(A+B)?

Yes, on architecture where `int` can't hold all range of values of `uint16_t`. In that particular case, the first expression first promotes the operands of `+` operator to `unsigned int`, while the second one carries the operation using `int` types. The second expression is the same as `C = A + B`, because `C` has type `uint16_t`. Except that particular case, on architectures where `int` can hold all range of values of `uint16_t`, both operands will be promoted to `int`. `C= static_cast<uint16_t>(A+B)` is the same as `C = A + B`.

> How implicit casting in case of expressions of unsigned int(with U literal)and uint8_t would work?

First both operands undergo *integral promotions*. `unsigned int` stays and `uint8_t` is promoted to `int`. Then the operands undergo *integral conversions*. Because one of the operands is `unsigned` and both operands have the same conversion rank, the signed operand is converted to unsigned type, ie. `int` is converted to `unsigned int`. [arithmetic operators and arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

> Is there also a difference between the order that it matters ie `1U*B;(unsined int * uint8_t )` or `B*1U;(uint8_t * uint8_t )`

No, the order of operands does not matter.

> Explicit casting would be C= static_cast<uint16_t>A+1U; or C= static_cast<uint16_t>(A+1U); C= static_cast<uint16_t>1UB; or C= static_cast<uint16_t>(1UB);. Is that correct Is there any difference between those lines?

`static_cast<uint16_t>1UB` is a syntax error. `C = static_cast<declatype(C)>(expr)` is always equal to `C = expr`.

> How the implicit casting in case of expressions would work. Is the normal order take into account?

I do not understand what is a "normal order". The operands and expression are evaluated according to their precedences.

> What would it be the final type of the expression?

> ```
>  C= 1U/(A-1U);  (unsigned int / (uint8_t -(unsigned int))
> ```

The expression on the right side of `operator=` is an rvalue of `unsigned int` type.

> ```
>  C= (C-(A/B))/B; (uint8_t -(uint8_t /(unsigned int))/(uint8_t)
> ```

The expression on the right side of `operator=` is an rvalue of `unsigned int` type.

> How should static_cast look in this case?

Like anywhere else `static_cast<type>(expr)`

> Only the first variable (1U or C) would define for the rest C= static_cast<uint8_t >(1U)/(A-1U);

Each operator evaluates it's operands separately, one or two expressions at a time. The order of evaluations (and thus promotions) is ordered according to precedence of operators. [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) and [precedence and associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

> How the implicit casting in case of standard functions would work?

Like with any other type according to the rules of integer promotions. `size_t` is just an implementation defined unsigned integer type.

> Explicit casting would be C= static_cast<uint16_t>sizeof(A) and C= static_cast<uint16_t>abs(-1*A). Is that correct?

Both expression are syntax error. It's `static_cast<type> ( expression )`. Braces are mandatory. For answer see above - doing `C = static_cast<decltype(C)>(expr)` is just equal to `C = expr`.

> What about C= static_cast<uint16_t>abs(-1)*A)?

What about it?

> How the implicit casting in case of function parameters would work.

When arguments are not part of elipsis in a variadic function call then the arguments are *converted* to the argument type.

> Explicit casting would be C= sum(static_cast<uint16_t>(A),static_cast<uint16_t>(B-1U/2U)). Is that correct?

Yes, but what for? They will be converted to `uint16_t` anyway.

> I saw in Opencv a similar to static_cast function called `saturate_cast`. Would it be a beter solution in any of the above cases?

"Better" is opinion based and vague. It depends on what you want to achieve. The `saturate_cast` is a [simple template](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/3rdparty/carotene/src/saturate_cast.hpp#L123) that specifically handles types with range grater then destination range. In such cases the argument is converted to the maximum/minimum of that type.

For further research,. the draft of c++ standard [is available online](https://eel.is/c++draft/).